# passing array to Constructor function and keep it public

Tags: javascript, oop

here is my code :

```
var BoxUtility = function() {
    var boxList = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
};

Object.defineProperties(BoxUtility, {
    totalArea: {
        value: function(){
           var x = 0;
           for(var i = 0, len = boxList.length; i <= len - 1; i++){
              x = x + boxList[i].area;
           };
        return x;
        }
     }
});
```

I'm trying to achieve this syntax for my Code :

```
var boxArray = [box01, box02, box03];
```

box are objects, box01.area => boxes have area property

```
var newElement = new BoxUtility(boxArray);
alert(newElement.totalArea);
```

I WANT TO SEE THE RESULT AS I EXPECT but I think boxList is in another scope

How can I reach it in defineProperties

Comment: Shouldnt it be this.boxList instead of boxList in that for loop?

Comment: Shouldn't `Array.prototype.pop.apply` be `Array.prototype.slice.apply`?

Comment: It passes to BoxUtility(Constructor function)

but I doesnt pass to totalArea Property via defineProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the value to a property of `this` in your constructor.

```
var BoxUtility = function() {
    // this.boxList
    this.boxList = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
};

// instance methods go on the prototype of the constructor
Object.defineProperties(BoxUtility.prototype, {
    totalArea: {

        // use get, instead of value, to execute this function when
        // we access the property.
        get: function(){
           var x = 0;

           // this.boxList
           for(var i = 0, len = this.boxList.length; i <= len - 1; i++){
              x = x + this.boxList[i].area;
           };
           return x;
        }
     }
});

var boxUtil = new BoxUtility([{area:123}, {area:456}]);
console.log(boxUtil.totalArea); // 579
```

Variable scope is *always* at the `function` level.  So you declared a local variable that is only usable inside your constructor function.  But every time you call the constructor function you get a new object (`this`). You add properties to `this` in order to have those properties accessible in your instance methods on the prototype.

Comment: var y = new BoxUitility(boxArray);
alert(y.totalArea) => WHY STILL IT SHOWS UNDEFINED ??

Comment: Sorry, you also need to define the property on `BoxUtility.prototype`. Functions that are on the prototype object of the constructor are shared with instances. Properties of the constructor function directly are not.  So you want `Object.defineProperties(BoxUtility.prototype, {`

Comment: thanks DEAR ALEX, U RIGHT . I USE PROTOTYPE for METHODS

I think becuz I want totalArea be a property I can use defineProperties Solution , I write my Answer Aswell, what do u think ?

Comment: Then define the function as a `get:` instead of a `value:` when creating the property.  `get:` declares a function to run when the proeprty is accessed. `value:` declares a value to return when the property is access. So if you return a function, you still have to execute it. I've updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
var BoxUtility = function() {
this.boxList = Array.prototype.pop.apply(arguments);
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    totalArea: {
        get: function(){
        var x = 0;
        for(var i = 0, len = this.boxList.length; i <= len - 1; i++){
            x = x + this.boxList[i].area;
        };
        return x;
        }
    }
});};


var y = new BoxUtility(boxArray);
alert(y.totalArea)
```

Comment: You don't need to put the data on `this` if the getter function shares the same scope as the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way to pass array as argument in constructer and declare function prototype for public access.

```
 function BoxUtility(boxArray) {
     this.boxArray = boxArray;
     this.len = boxArray.length;

  }
 Color.prototype.getAverage = function () {
      var sum = 0;
      for(let i = 0;i<this.len;i++){
       sum+=this.boxArray[i];

  }
   return parseInt(sum);
};

var red = new BoxUtility(boxArray);

alert(red.getAverage());
```